# how to set maximum time for spring data mongo query

Tags: mongodb, spring-mongo

I want to kill slow queries which run for more than 2 hours.

can i use socket-timeout in MongoOptions class for killing slow queries in spring data mongo db?

Please help.

Comment: Two hours is well beyond a "slow query" and hopefully just a "long running query". Unless that sort of query time is expected & acceptable based on your data or server resources, you should post a separate question on tuning the query (if you haven't already done so).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket timeouts will close the connection from the client point of view, but the server will continue to process the query if there is still work in progress (for example, fetching a batch of data).

If you are using a version of MongoDB server prior to 2.6, you can kill long running operations via the [`db.killOp()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.killOp/) command .. however you have to ensure that you are killing the expected client operations and not internal server threads. It can be helpful to add a unique [`$comment`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/comment/) to your long running queries so they can be identified via [`db.currentOp(true)`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/).

MongoDB 2.6+ added a new [`maxTimeMS`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.maxTimeMS/) cursor option to ensure the server kills the cursor after a certain amount of cumulative processing time (in milliseconds). You'll need to be using the 2.12 (or newer) version of the MongoDB Java driver (which can be set in your `pom.xml` with `<mongodb.driver.version>`).

For more background on `maxTimeMS` and socket timeouts see: [maxTimeMS() and Query Optimizer Introspection in MongoDB 2.6](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/83621787773/maxtimems-and-query-optimizer-introspection-in).

Comment: Thanks Stennie for your answer.

Comment: I am using spring data mongo query, there is no option for using maxTimeMS with it. SO i have to use db.currentOp() command to kill that operation.

Comment: Spring data builds on the MongoDB Java driver, so you should be able to pass through cursor options or (worst case) call the underlying driver. It looks like someone contributed a pull request which has been merged for Spring Data 1.6.0 RC1: [DATAMONGO-957: Add support for query modifiers](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-957).